# Persist facebook claims and use from User.Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-identity, .net-core-3.1, claims

I have this working code, which logs into via facebook and returns data such as

```
faceBookOptions.Fields.Add("picture");
            faceBookOptions.CallbackPath = "/ExternalLoginCallback";
            faceBookOptions.Events = new OAuthEvents
            {
                OnCreatingTicket = (context) =>
                {
                    ClaimsIdentity identity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
                    string profileImg = context.User.GetProperty("picture").GetProperty("data").GetProperty("url").ToString();
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Picture, profileImg));
                    context.HttpContext.User = context.Principal;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
```

I now want to access this claim in my razor view:

```
@User.Identity.Claims
```

these claims has no profile picture!

ive searched SO and found many relating posts. but they dont use .net core 3.1, they have actual accountControllers and callback methods. in .net core 3.1 it all happens "behind the scenes"

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

https://haacked.com/archive/2019/07/16/external-claims/

i found this very detailed guide on why this is so complicated and how to work around it